# Reopen same alert again and again

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm making ionic 3 application. There is verify otp functionality in a sign up page. When the user clicks on sign up button then an alert will be open with otp input with cancel, verify and resend button. What I want to do when user clicks on resend button the same alert should open. I have done this by copying the whole alert code in resend button handler. but it's just opening in first time only. I want to reopen this alert infinitely when a user clicks on resend button.

Below is my alert code

```
{

let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'OTP Sent. Verify OTP',
    inputs: [{
        name: 'otp',
        placeholder: 'OTP',
        value: this.otp
    }, ],
    buttons: [{
            text: 'Cancel',
            role: 'cancel',
            handler: data => {
                console.log('Cancel clicked');
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Verify',
            handler: data => {
                console.log(data.otp);
                if (this.responseData.data.otp_sent == data.otp) {
                    console.log("verfiied");
                } else {
                    // invalid login
                    return false;
                }
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Resend',
            handler: data => {
                this.authService.postData('mobile=' + this.responseData.data.mobile, 'user/resend').then((result) => {
                    // console.log(this.otpResend);
                    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                        title: 'OTP Sent. Verify OTP',
                        inputs: [{
                            name: 'otp',
                            placeholder: 'OTP',
                            value: this.otp
                        }, ],
                        buttons: [{
                                text: 'Cancel',
                                role: 'cancel',
                                handler: data => {
                                    console.log('Cancel clicked');
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                text: 'Verify',
                                handler: data => {
                                    console.log(data.otp);
                                    if (this.responseData.data.otp_sent == data.otp) {
                                        console.log("verfiied");
                                    } else {
                                        // invalid login
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                text: 'Resend',
                                handler: data => {
                                    this.authService.postData('mobile=' + this.responseData.data.mobile, 'user/resend').then((result) => {
                                        // console.log(this.otpResend);

                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                    alert.present();

                });
            }
        }
    ]
});
alert.present();
}
```

Comment: its call only one time so need to call recursively.....

Answer (score 3):

Make a resend function

```
    resend(){

         this.authService.postData('mobile=' + this.responseData.data.mobile, 'user/resend').then((result) => {
                                // console.log(this.otpResend);
                                let alert1 = this.alertCtrl.create({
                                    title: 'OTP Sent. Verify OTP',
                                    inputs: [{
                                        name: 'otp',
                                        placeholder: 'OTP',
                                        value: this.otp
                                    }, ],
                                    buttons: [{
                                            text: 'Cancel',
                                            role: 'cancel',
                                            handler: data => {
                                                console.log('Cancel clicked');
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: 'Verify',
                                            handler: data => {
                                                console.log(data.otp);
                                                if (this.responseData.data.otp_sent == data.otp) {
                                                    console.log("verfiied");
                                                } else {
                                                    // invalid login
                                                    return false;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: 'Resend',
                                            handler: data => {
                                                this.authService.postData('mobile=' + this.responseData.data.mobile, 'user/resend').then((result) => {
                                                    resend();
                                                    // console.log(this.otpResend);

                                                });
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                });
                                alert1.present();

    }
```

Then call it

```
 {
            text: 'Resend',
            handler: data =>{
              resend();
            }
}
```